# angular scope variable is not visible inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am newbie to Angular and tried to call a controller method with a hyperlink by following way:

```
<a href="" ng-click="getAssetDetail(contractNum)"> {{item.contractnum}} </a>
```

Where **item.contractnum** is a scope variable which is visible when I pull it out from **'a'** tag but inside the tag its not visible, also I want to pass it back to controller method **getAssetDetail** but can't figure out how to accomplish it. Please suggest.

EDIT: 
View:

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] ">
            <td><a href="" ng-click="getAssetDetail(item.contractnum)">contract number {{item.contractnum}} </a> <br /> Serial Number:{{item.serialNum}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.getAssetDetail = function (contractNum) {

        //My Code Here
    }

 pagedItems=[{"contractnum":"123", "serialNum":"ABC1" },
             {"contractnum":"121", "serialNum":"ABC2" },
             {"contractnum":"124", "serialNum":"ABC3" },
             {"contractnum":"125", "serialNum":"ABC4" } 
            ]
```

Comment: have you tried `ng-click="getAssetDetail(item.contractNum)"` ?

Comment: can you provide fiddle with problem?

Comment: @EvandroSilva : I have tried that but I can't see the encapsulated value of {{item.contractnum}} within the 'a' tag, is there any other way to show scope variables inside the anchor tag?

Comment: @Grundy: Please see that I can't see the angular scope variable inside the 'a' tag

Comment: @tom without code sample it seems work

Comment: @Grundy  <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] ">
                <td><a href="" ng-click="getAssetDetail(item.contractnum)">contract number {{item.contractnum}} </a> <br /> Serial Number:{{item.serialNum}} <br /> Job Name: {{item.jobName}} <br /> Model Number: {{item.modelNum}}</td>
            </tr>

Comment: @tom add it and js part to your post, not in comment

Comment: @tom, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: also provide what is `pagedItems`

Comment: pagedItems is an array of values I used it for paging , Do you need more information?

Comment: add in post sample data in `pagedItems` like `pagedItems=...`

Comment: @Grundy Added the Array! Now can you provide your feedback!

Comment: Make a fiddle. We can't see where you are loading the controller in the DOM. Even if we could, this should be working. Something else is going on and none of us will be able to tell without a fiddle.

Comment: Ok! I will make the fiddle and update the question! Thanks for your responses !

Answer (score 0):

if you realy have `pagedItems` like

```
pagedItems=[{"contractnum":"123", "serialNum":"ABC1" },
         {"contractnum":"121", "serialNum":"ABC2" },
         {"contractnum":"124", "serialNum":"ABC3" },
         {"contractnum":"125", "serialNum":"ABC4" } 
        ]
```

so you wrong use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), because pass to it simple object like `pagedItems[0]`

```
{"contractnum":"123", "serialNum":"ABC1" }
```

so *item* in this case is `123`,`ABC1` that realy don't have property `contractnum` and others

for solving you can use

```
ng-repeat="item in pagedItems"
```

or save in `pagedItems` arrays of object like [[{},...],[{},...],[{},...]]

or use [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) like [*limitTo*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) for select only needed element in `pagedItems`

Answer (score 0):

If your pagedItems data is meant to be just for one page of data, then you need to change the ng-repeat line to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems">
```

If your pagedItems data is meant to be all the data for every page, then you need to change your pagedItems data structure to be an object with properties for each page number like:

```
pageItems = {
    "1": [{"contractnum": "121"}, ... etc],
    "2": [{"contractnum": "131"}, ... etc]
    ... etc ...
}
```

or as an array of arrays where the index in the outer array is the page number (or perhaps pagenumber - 1) and the inner arrays are arrays of objects for each page like:

```
pageItems = [
    [{"contractnum": "121"}, ... etc],
    [{"contractnum": "131"}, ... etc]
]
```

Your existing ng-repeat line should then work.